# How to get difference between 2 columns

Tags: sql, database, mysql

I have a query that is producing something like this:

```
StartTimestamp  |  EndTimestamp
================================
100             | 450
--------------------------------
150             | 500
```

I'd like the result to also include the difference between EndTimestamp and StartTimestamp:

```
StartTimestamp  |  EndTimestamp  |  Difference
==============================================
100             | 450            | 350
----------------------------------------------
150             | 600            | 450
```

How do I do this in MySQL?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the table is named, say, `t`:

```
SELECT t.StartTimestamp, t.EndTimestamp, t.EndTimestamp - t.StartTimestamp AS Difference
FROM   &c
```

Of course, you don't need the `t.` parts in the select's columns if the undecorated names `StartTimestamp` and `EndTimestamp` are unambiguous in the context of the rest of your query.

Comment: @Alex... I want to check if `Difference` is greater than `zero`. how can I check this???

Comment: You can use `SELECT StartTimestamp, EndTimestamp, EndTimestamp - StartTimestamp AS Difference, case when ( EndTimestamp - StartTimestamp)>0 then 'Greater than 0' else 'Less than/equal to 0' end as My_Flag
FROM   mytablename`