# Get column name where values differ between two rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table with lots of columns. Sometimes I need to find differences between two rows. I can do it just by scrolling through screen but it is dull. I'm looking for a query that will do this for me, something like

```
SELECT columns_for_id_1 != columns_for_id_2
FROM  xyz
WHERE id in (1,2)
```

Table:

```
id col1 col2 col3 col4
1  qqq  www  eee  rrr
2  qqq  www  XXX  rrr
```

Result:

```
"Different columns: id, col3"
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

**UPDATE**

Another example as wanted:
What I have (table has more than 50 column, not only 7):

```
Id| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 | Col6 |
==============================================
1 | aaa  | bbb  | ccc  | ddd  | eee  | fff  |
----------------------------------------------
2 | aaa  | XXX  | ccc  | YYY  | eee  | fff  |
```

Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE Id = 1 OR Id = 2 
AND "columns value differs"
```

Query result: `"Id, Col2, Col4"`

OR something like:

    `Id|Col2 |Col4 |
    ===============
    1 |bbb  |ddd  |
    ---------------
    2 |XXX  |YYY  |`

Right now I have to scroll through more than 50 columns to see if rows are the same, it's not efficient and prone to mistakes. I don't want any long query like 
`SELECT (COMPARE Id1.Col1 with Id2.Col1 if different then print "Col1 differs", COMPARE Id1.Col2 with Id2.Col2...)`  because I will compare the rows myself faster ;)

Comment: Add more sample data, and adjust the expected result accordingly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get difference between 2 columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482033/how-to-get-difference-between-2-columns)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
SELECT col, MIN(VAL) AS val1, MAX(val) AS val2
FROM (
SELECT id, val, col
FROM (
   SELECT id,  [col1], [col2], [col3], [col4]
   FROM mytable
   WHERE id IN (1,2)) AS src
UNPIVOT (
   val FOR col IN ([col1], [col2], [col3], [col4])) AS unpvt ) AS t
GROUP BY col 
HAVING MIN(val) <> MAX(val)
```

**Output:**

```
col  val1 val2
================
col3 eee  XXX
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple query, may be help you

```
    SELECT (CASE WHEN a.col1 <> b.col1 THEN 'Different Col1' 
                 WHEN a.col2 <> b.col2 THEN 'Different Col2' 
                 ...
                 ELSE 'No Different' END) --You can add only required columns here
    FROM xyz AS a 
    INNER JOIN xyz AS b ON b.id = 1 --First Record
    WHERE a.id = 2 --Second record to compare
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on SQL Server 2012 then you can also use LEAD/LAG windowed funuction to do this. MSDN Reference is here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx

```
select 
id, 
col1,
col2,
col3,
col4,
stuff(diff_cols,len(diff_cols-1),1,'') diff_cols 
from 
(
SELECT 
id, 
col1,
col2,
col3,
col4,
concat
(
'Different columns:',
CASE 
WHEN LEAD(id, 1,0) OVER (ORDER BY id) <> id THEN 'id,'
WHEN LEAD(col1, 1,0) OVER (ORDER BY id) <> col1 THEN 'col1,'
WHEN LEAD(col2, 1,0) OVER (ORDER BY id) <> col2 THEN 'col2,'
WHEN LEAD(col3, 1,0) OVER (ORDER BY id) <> col3 THEN 'col3,'
WHEN LEAD(col4, 1,0) OVER (ORDER BY id) <> col4 THEN 'col4,'
) diff_cols
FROM xyz
) tmp
```